# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skater'

Tags: python-3.x

When I tried to `conda` or `pip install` the package `'skater'`, the terminal told me that

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skater'".

Then I Google this package and find this package can be found and I download it from *Github(a Zip in 'tar' form)*. However, I failed again to pip it.

Comment: more details can be found in [link](https://github.com/oracle/Skater)

Answer (score 0):

To install this package with conda, use the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge skater
```

I installed it. Problem solved, program is running.